# Bad arithmetic in c

Tags: c, arithmetic-expressions

I'm writing a longer program in C and when I try to run it I get `floating point exception error : 8`. This is just a snippet of a code due to which I'm getting an error in my main program. Why am I getting an error when `a = (1/i+1)`?

```
int main()
{
    double a;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        a = 1/i+1;
        printf("a = %lf",a);

    }
}
```

Comment: Multiplicative operators have higher precedence than additive operators.

Comment: There use to be times where programming was called "applied mathematics" ... *sigh*

Comment: `floating point expectation error`. What?

Comment: OT: The `l` length modifier here `%lf` is useless as the `f` conversion specifier expects a `double` already.

Comment: @DeiDei: To be fair, it's not like an integer operation throwing a floating-point exception makes any more sense. Historical baggage ahoy!

Comment: The error is because you do `1/0`. But note correcting that will *not* fix the next problem: you are working in integers. (*Surely* this is a duplicate!?)

Comment: @RadLexus: *shh*, you'll ruin the *next* duplicate question the OP's going to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial value of `i` is `0` in this expression:

```
a = 1 / i + 1;
```

Since `i` has `int` type, you are evaluating a integer division by zero, which invokes undefined behavior.

It is somewhat misleading that this leads to the message `floating point exception error : 8`, but perfectly compatible with the notion of undefined behavior.

Note that you need to change the expression to force evaluation as floating point:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        double a = 1.0 / i + 1;
        printf("a = %f\n", a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The first answer when i = 0 is "inf".  The results of the loop are to be stored in a static array thus when I want to the get the sum of the array i will also get "inf".

Comment: @BartlomiejMlynarkiewicz: Just don't divide by zero.

Comment: I came to that solution, thankfully its just practice questions for a test Im doing and the answer will be written on paper thus Im not too sure I if would get deducted a mark for initialising the loop with 1 instead of 0.

Comment: @BartlomiejMlynarkiewicz: I purposely kept the `i=0` initial step for you to experience the difference between integer and floating point division by zero. For your purpose, you have to decide what initial value to use for `i` and whether to use `1.0 / i + 1` or `1.0 / (i + 1)`.

Comment: @chqrlie: I eventually understand, thank you.